# How can we dispay a zoomed div like this

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Please how can I display a zoomed html div like in the picture above:

After we click on a small div to zoom it, we show a new zoomed div (we can close it).

[image]

Comment: I believe the desired effect you're trying to achieve is a modal https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a modal. You can use a bootstrap [modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/) or [create your own](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp) .

Comment: Thank you, now after you showed me the concept, I will use it with Material UI